# RxJava: Is there an Observable.cachedDefer() operator, or some equivalent?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

Is there a safe way to defer the creation of an `Observable<T>`, but upon creation cache it for a period of time before it must create it again?

```
Observable.cachedDefer(() -> createExpensiveFiniteObservable().cache(), 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

I have data sets that are expensive to construct and I want them cached long enough to support a process, but let them expire approximately between each run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the functionality to do this to *[rxjava-extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras)*. The code below depends on *rxjava-extras* 0.6.8-RC2 or later (which is on Maven Central).

Run the `main` method below and you will see these results which seem to match the behaviour you desire (a reset of the cache whenever the time gap to next subscribe is >=5 seconds):

```
source emits Tue Oct 13 21:00:16 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:16 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:16 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:16 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:16 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:16 AEDT 2015
source emits Tue Oct 13 21:00:31 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:31 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:31 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:31 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:31 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:31 AEDT 2015
source emits Tue Oct 13 21:00:46 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:46 AEDT 2015
Tue Oct 13 21:00:46 AEDT 2015
...
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Observable<Date> source = Observable
      .defer(() -> 
         Observable
           .just(new Date())
           .doOnNext(
              d -> System.out.println("source emits " + d)));

    CloseableObservableWithReset<Date> cached = 
        Obs.cache(source, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.computation());
    Observable<Date> o = cached
        .observable()
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> cached.reset());
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        o.doOnNext(System.out::println).subscribe();
        Thread.sleep((i % 5 + 1)*1000);
    }
    cached.close();
}
```

Note that to reset the cache on every emission as well then where you see

```
.doOnSubscribe(() -> cached.reset())
```

put

```
.doOnSubscribe(() -> cached.reset())
.doOnNext(x -> cached.reset())
```

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping you would if it didn't exist. I'll play with this code sample later. Btw is it possible to create a similar operator that does the same thing, only it clears the cache after a period of no emissions/additional subscriptions?

Comment: Could be done I'm sure, I'll have a look at that one.

Comment: Hey Thomas, this solution doesn't complete properly. I'll complete the fix and the unit tests in rxjava-extras and let you know when ready.

Comment: Np let me know if I can do anything to help. No rush! Your work adds so much value to what I do.

Comment: updated with rxjava-extras 0.6.8-RC2 additions. Let me know what you think (no rush from me either!). Thanks for the offer of help.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I'll check it out again today.